# Creating objects from arrays with repeating values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with repeating values:

```
[ ['Deer Skin', 1], ['Bear Skin', 1], ['Deer Skin', 1], ['Cougar Skin', 2] ... ]
```

I want to compare them by the sting value of `index[0]` and remove duplicates while storing the result in a new object.

The resulting values would look like:

```
[ {name: 'Deer Skin', quantity: 4}, {name: 'Bear Skin', quantity: 5}, {name: 'Cougar Skin', quantity: 4} ... ]
```

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here. Right now I have an array of objects with all initial duplicate array values removed:

```
[
{name: "Deer Skin", quantity: 0}
{name: "Bear Skin", quantity: 0}
{name: "Cougar Skin", quantity: 0}
...
```

But I'm not understanding how I can map the values of:

```
[ ['Deer Skin', 1], ['Bear Skin', 1], ['Deer Skin', 1], ['Cougar Skin', 2] ... ]
```

to above object.

Comment: Do do have to map anything. Just iterate over the array and add the value of `element[1]` to `obj[element[0]]`.

Comment: @FelixKling Would that work with the `value` of the item? I think `obj['Deer Skin']` doesn't exist.

Comment: see under "Unique by..." heading https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/2096695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.reduce` to achieve this. Here I have initialized the accumulator (`acc`) to be an empty object `{}`. As the array is iterated, the ternary operator decides whether to add the quantity to the current value of the key (`elem[0]`) (we only add if we have seen it before - if we tried to add to something we hadn't of seen before we would get `NaN` as our value) or whether to create a new key-value pair (if we haven't seen the key value before).

See working example below:

```js
const arr = [
  ['Deer Skin', 1],
  ['Bear Skin', 1],
  ['Deer Skin', 1],
  ['Cougar Skin', 2]
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  elem[0] in acc ? acc[elem[0]] += elem[1] : acc[elem[0]] = elem[1];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @KylePfahler no worries :D

Answer (score 1):

Using Object.entries, array.reduce, and array destructuring:

```js
const data = [
  ['Deer Skin', 1],
  ['Bear Skin', 1],
  ['Deer Skin', 1],
  ['Cougar Skin', 2]
];

const reduceData = (data) => data.reduce((acc, [key, count]) => {
  if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = 0; // If key doesn't exist yet, add and set count to zero
  acc[key] += count;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(reduceData(data));

// But if you want an array, use Object.entries
console.log(Object.entries(reduceData(data)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't mentioned the structure of the new object in which you're going to store the uniques, you could do something like this:

```
const arrayItems = [ ['Deer Skin', 1], ['Bear Skin', 1], ['Deer Skin', 2], ['Cougar Skin', 2] ... ];
const deduplicatedObj = {};

for(let item of arrayItems){
    deduplicatedObj[item[0]] = item[1];
}

console.log(deduplicatedObj); // This should be an object with key as 'Deer Skin' and value as 1, and so on.
```

Since you are storing the value in an object, and an object can have only unique keys, when you assign `item[1]` to `deduplicatedObj[item[0]]`, it will overwrite the pre-existing value if any.

The `deduplicatedObj` will look something like this:

```
deduplicatedObj = {
    'Deer Skin': 2,
    'Bear Skin': 1,
    'Cougar Skin': 2
}
```